# Global functions on smooth varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field. Let $X\to \mathrm{Spec}\:k$ be a smooth morphism. Is there a smooth separated morphism $X'\to \mathrm{Spec}\:k$ such that $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)\approx \Gamma(X', \mathcal{O}_{X'})$ as $k$-algebras?

Comment: What is the definition of $X'$?

Comment: @auniket just an arbitrary scheme admitting a morphism with the described properties